# How do I properly configure host server net adapters when using Hyper-V?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, hyper-v, virtual-machines, dhcp

I am converting a number of physical servers to virtual ones, and I have a question regarding configuring the physical adapters on the host server. I am new to virtual machines, and have a nagging configuration question regarding how to configure the physical adapters on the host computer

Here is the situation:

Host server (HOST-1) has 4 physical adapters, adapters 0,1,2,3 -

Adapter 0 is reserved for communicating with the host and has a static IP assigned (192.168.1.11).

Adapters 1-3 are bridged to Hyper-V, and can be configured in hyper-v with static IP addresses for VM-1 (192.168.1.101), VM-2(192.168.1.102), and VM-3 (192.168.1.103).

However, still show up as network adapters for the host computer. Should these (on HOST-1) be configured with the same static IP as the VMs they refer to? This seems to cause confusion for my DNS server, who wants to talk to HOST-1 on the same IP addresses (.11,.101,.102,and .103).

I then assigned dynamic addresses to the adapters on HOST-1, which worked 2 out of three times, except that now I have DHCP entries for HOST-1 on three IPs where it should not exist.

Is there a clean way to tell HOST-1 to ignore the three adapters that are bridged to the VMs? I tried unbinding them on HOST-1, but that caused the bridging to stop working.

One of my concerns is that I have another 7-10 host machines to set up, and if each has roughly the same adapter setup, it would create ~30 "ghost" DHCP and related DNS entries, and I'm trying to demonstrate the ease of using VMs, not the complexity :).

Am I just missing something simple here? I'm running Server 2008 R2 on a 2008 R2 domain, so there are no backward compatibility considerations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've created an external virtual switch bound to those NICs then you shouldn't have TCP/IP bound to those NICs unless you check the box "allow management operating system to share this network adapter", which it sounds like you didn't do and don't want if you have a dedicated NIC for the Host communication. It sounds like you enabled TCP/IP on those NICs, which you should disable. Those NICs should not have an ip address for the Host, the only thing that should be bound to those NICs is the "Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch" component.

Please post a screenshot of the virtual switch configuration for one of those virtual switches and post screenshots of the NIC properties for the accompanying NIC.

Comment: Actually, you just solved my problem. For some reason, the "allow Management operating system to share this network adapter" was checked by default when the VM was created. Looking back , i suspect this is because I initially conencted the adapter when I build the VM, and not through the settings for the hyper-V manager.